# java spark cassandra mini-program gives datastax driver exceptions: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input 'FROM'

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm doing something dumb with my first Spark/Cassandra program using Java and am hoping someone can help 
me figure out why I am getting this errror:

```
: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
```

The setup is

```
Create keyspace test with replicaton={'class':strategy name, 
                'replication_factor': No of replications on different nodes}
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
use test;
CREATE TABLE KeyValue ( key varchar, value bigint, PRIMARY KEY (key));
INSERT INTO KeyValue (key, value) VALUES ('afoo', 100);
```

And the code (below) is brain dead simple... I am using a 'select' clause, so I'm not sure why the driver is not
picking up the columns I specify.

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import java.io.Serializable;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo;

public class JavaDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sparkMaster = "local[2]";
    String cassandraHost = "localhost";
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost);

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkMaster, "basicquerycassandra", conf);
    CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(conf);
    JavaRDD<KeyValue> rdd = javaFunctions(sc)
            .cassandraTable("test", "keyvalue", mapRowTo(KeyValue.class))
            .withConnector(connector).select("key", "value")
            .where("key = 'afoo'");

    rdd.foreach(row -> System.out.println("got item" + row));
  }

  public static class KeyValue implements Serializable {
    private String key;
    private Integer value;
    public KeyValue() {
    }
    public static KeyValue newInstance(String k, Integer v) {
      KeyValue kv = new KeyValue();
      kv.setKey(k);
      kv.setValue(v);
      return kv;
    }
    public String getKey() {
      return key;
    }
    public Integer getValue() {
      return value;
    }
    void setKey(String k) {
      this.key = k;
    }
    void setValue(Integer v) {
      this.value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "KeyValue{" +
              "key='" + key + '\'' +
              ", value=" + value +
              '}';
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I can avoid the syntax error if i update the code as below... it is not yet exactly what i want.  I will fiddle with it tomorrow and post an answer if no one beats me to it.  I'm close ;^)

```
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkMaster, "basicquerycassandra", conf);
    CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(conf);
    CassandraTableScanJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = javaFunctions(sc)
            .cassandraTable("test", "keyvalue")
            .select("key", "value")
            .where("key = 'afoo'");

    rdd.foreach(row -> System.out.println("got item" + row));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide any Column Mapper, spark connector will use default `JavaBeanColumnMapper` e.g. basically it's normal java reflection like BeanUtils from apache. This will require either public constructor or public getter/setter for all selected columns.

So in order to make it work, you should have public constructor like below, or define setter/getter methods as public for `key` attribute. Hope it helps.

Public constructor:

```
    public KeyValue(String key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Public setter/getter:

```
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Comment: wow.. you're right !  Just changed the two setters to be visibility public and it worked like a charm.   thanks !